Shiny App RenderDT not working after deployment (AJAX then cannot unclass an environment)
I have a Shiny app that was working perfectly fine until last week. After deployment, I initially encountered an AJAX error when trying to render a DataTable. Based on suggestions from various sources, I implemented `server = FALSE` in my `renderDT` calls. Now, the AJAX error is gone, but I'm facing a new issue with the error message: "cannot unclass an environment."  Here's a simplified version of my app:
**UI**

`library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(shinyAce)
library(reticulate)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage(
    theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
    collapsible = TRUE,
    title = "IMPACT JMMI Dashboard",
    position = "fixed-top",
    
    tabPanel("API Documentation",
      div(class = "content-wrapper",
        fluidRow(
          box(
            status = "primary",
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            width = 12,
            br(),
            br(),
            br(),
            br(),
            
            tags$h2(tags$b("The JMMI API Documentation")),
            
            br(),
            
            tags$h3(tags$b("1. API Main Functions")),
            br(),
            tags$h5(tags$b("Full Data")),
            
            fluidRow(
              column(width = 6,
                aceEditor("code_editor3", 
                  mode = "python", 
                  theme = "tomorrow_night_bright", 
                  height = "270px",
                  value = "
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://jmmi-db-2024-108.azure-api.net/impact-jmmi-api-open/full_data'
json_body = {
  'country': 'BGD',
  'start_date': '2020-04-01',
  'end_date': '2020-04-27',
  'heading_format': 'names'
}

response = requests.get(url, params=json_body)
df = pd.DataFrame(response.json()['data'])
"),
                fluidRow(
                  column(2,
                    tags$div(
                      style = "position: relative;", 
                      actionButton("send_request3", "Send Request", style = "background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 12px; padding: 5px 10px;"),
                      tags$div(
                        id = "loading-spinner3",
                        style = "display: none; position: absolute; left: 200%; top: 50%; transform: translate(10px, -50%);",  
                        tags$img(src = "https://i.gifer.com/ZZ5H.gif", height = "20px", width = "20px")
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
              ),
              column(width = 6,
                DTOutput("table_output3")
              )
            ),
            
            br(),
            br(),
            
            tags$h5(tags$b("Price Data")),
            
            fluidRow(
              column(width = 6,
                aceEditor("code_editor4", 
                  mode = "python", 
                  theme = "tomorrow_night_bright", 
                  height = "290px",
                  value = "
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://jmmi-db-2024-108.azure-api.net/impact-jmmi-api-open/price_data'
json_body = {
  'country': 'AFG',
  'start_date': '2022-04-01',
  'end_date': '2022-04-27',
  'heading_format': 'names',
  'items': ['rice','soap'],
}

response = requests.get(url, params=json_body)
df = pd.DataFrame(response.json()['data'])
"),
                fluidRow(
                  column(2,
                    tags$div(
                      style = "position: relative;",  
                      actionButton("send_request4", "Send Request", style = "background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 12px; padding: 5px 10px;"),
                      tags$div(
                        id = "loading-spinner4",
                        style = "display: none; position: absolute; left: 200%; top: 50%; transform: translate(10px, -50%);",  
                        tags$img(src = "https://i.gifer.com/ZZ5H.gif", height = "20px", width = "20px")
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
              ),
              column(width = 6,
                DTOutput("table_output4")
              )
            ),
            
            br(),
            br()
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)`

**Server**
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(reticulate)

reticulate::py_install(c("requests", "pandas"))
pandas <- import("pandas")
requests <- import("requests")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  process_request <- function(editor_input, spinner_id, output_id) {
    observeEvent(input[[paste0('send_request', gsub("code_editor", "", editor_input))]], {
      req(input[[editor_input]])
      
      # Show spinner
      runjs(paste0("$('#", spinner_id, "').show();"))
      
      # Save the Python code to a temporary file
      temp_code_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".py")
      writeLines(input[[editor_input]], temp_code_file)
      
      tryCatch({
        py_run_file(temp_code_file)
        
        # Ensure proper conversion from Python DataFrame to R DataFrame
        df <- reticulate::py_to_r(py$df)
        
        # Render DataTable
        output[[output_id]] <- renderDT({
          datatable(df, options = list(
            pageLength = 5,
            scrollX = TRUE,
            lengthChange = FALSE,
            searching = FALSE
          )) %>%
            formatStyle(
              columns = names(df),
              fontSize = '8px'
            )
        }, server = FALSE)
        
        # Hide the loading spinner
        runjs(paste0("$('#", spinner_id, "').hide();"))
        
      }, error = function(e) {
        showNotification(paste("An error occurred:", e$message), type = "error")
        runjs(paste0("$('#", spinner_id, "').hide();"))
      })
    })
  }

  process_request("code_editor3", "loading-spinner3", "table_output3")
  process_request("code_editor4", "loading-spinner4", "table_output4")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`

Issue:
The app worked perfectly last week, but now after deployment, I get a new error: "cannot unclass an environment" when trying to render the tables. I previously encountered an AJAX error and resolved it by adding `server = FALSE` to the renderDT calls, but now I'm stuck with this new issue.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Recently, an AJAX error has been reported to the DT Github repository. Perhaps it's the same. So far, no solution has been given.
